# Specify cache_key yourself for ActiveModel Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a multi-tenant solution where I would like to cache the outcome of the serializers.

Since the cache should be different for the different users, I would like to specify the cache_key myself (e.g. "/accounts/1/tags"). Is this at all possible with the current ActiveModel Serializer Gem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the account will return the same information for any user associated with it:

```
class AccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :balance
  has_many :transactions
  cached
  delegate :cache_key, to: :object
end
```